# Asignamiento de listas

Tags: python

```
a = [0,0]
b = a
b[0] += 1
print(a)
```

Output:

```
 [1, 0]
```

Porque `a` cambia cuando modifico `b`?

Comment: No conozco de [tag:python] pero tiene pinta que al hacer `b = a` estás haciendo una referencia y no una creación.

Comment: Pero si hago una variable de tipo float (por ejemplo) y la igualo a otra. Al cambiar la segunda no varia el resultado de la primera y viceversa.

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11222482/3045491)

Comment: Gracias humano! :)

Comment: Nada.  A ver si alguien te contesta con más información y se gana la aceptacion de respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables en python no tienen el mismo significado con el que se usa en programación tradicional de servir de *almacenamiento de un valor*. Sirven más como un mecanismo de etiquetar objetos para operar con ellos.

Cuando tu dices que *"asignas un valor a una variable"*, lo que realmente estás haciendo es *"dar nombre a un objeto"*. Y cuando dices que *"asignas a una variable el valor de otra"*, lo que realmente haces es *"crear un nuevo alias"*.

Por ejemplo,

```
a = 1  # etiqueta el entero '1' con el nombre "a"
b = a  # "b" apunta también al entero '1' que apuntaba "a"
a = 2  # "a" apunta al entero '2', "b" sigue apuntando al '1'
```

Estas variables no se crean para guardar los valores. De hecho todos los enteros desde -1 a 254 están creados desde el comienzo en el intérprete python como optimización (Si hay interés sobre *cuándo se crean los objetos en python* hace tiempo escribí un artículo sobre el [ciclo de vida de los objetos](http://blog.ch3m4.org/2013/11/09/python-eficiente-sobre-la-vida-de-los-objetos/))

¿Qué pasa con las listas? Pues que son **entidades mutables**. Lo que es visto como "asignaciones" son meros aliases del mismo objeto. Si el objeto muta, todos los aliases verán la mutación porque se trata del mismo objeto:

```
a = [0,0]  # etiquetas la lista [0,0] con el nombre "a"
b = a  # etiquetas la misma lista con el nombre "b"
b[0] += 1  # alteras un elemneto de la lista
```

No hay dos lista, tan sólo una lista con dos nombres.

Para evitar que suceda esto la solución es crear una nueva lista para `b`:

```
a = [0,0]
b = a[:]  # creación de una copia de la lista
b[0] += 1
```

El operador `[:]` de *rebanado* (*slicing*), sin argumentos, es el modo habitual de indicar que se está creando una copia completa de una lista (*OJO, que no siempre es así*). En realidad valdría cualquier operación sobre la lista que la deje *invariante*, por ejemplo `a*1` (replicar una vez la lista) es más rápido con lista largas, pero da más lugar a confusión.

La advertencia anterior es debida a que las listas pueden incluir referencias a otras listas e, incluso, autoreferencias a sí misma. Sería un **objeto compuesto** que el operador `[:]` no es capaz de replicar. Te puede ayudar el módulo `copy` para ciertos casos, pero siempre hay que saber qué se esta haciendo:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, [...]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b
[1, 2, [1, 2, [...]]]
>>> b[0] = 3
>>> b
[3, 2, [1, 2, [...]]]
>>> b[2][0] = 4
>>> b
[3, 2, [4, 2, [...]]]
>>> a
[4, 2, [...]]
>>> import copy
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b
[4, 2, [...]]
>>> b[2][0] = 5
>>> b
[5, 2, [...]]
>>> a
[4, 2, [...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu haces un asignamiento de una lista, como este:

`b = a`

En realidad no tienes dos listas, `b` contiene la referencia a la asignacion del elemento `a`, es decir, a un puntero.

Es decir cuando interactues con la variable `b` esta apunta a la variable `a` por tanto estaras modificando a la variable `a`.

La solucion a tu problema seria algo como esto:

```
a = [0,0]
b = list(a)
b[0] += 1

print(a)
```

Resultado:

> [0, 0]

Con la funcion `list()` puedes crear una lista basada en una lista previamente creada, es decir `b` no contendra una referencia sino que contendra una lista totalmente independiente.

Espero te ayude.

Mas informacion sobre [list()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)